# How get and storage data value of the html object tag in variable for compare via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

The page is in aspx and html/javascript.

I’m looking for how to get the value of the data file content of the html object tag in the variable **ObjText** to compare via javascript and display or not the div

If the file **Alerte_PageLogin1.txt** content is N/A in this case the div is hidden

I tried full example on other post of the site but none works

**Default.aspx**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache" content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive: no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive: no-cache">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="webLink">
            <div id="DivAlertePageLogin">
                <p style="background: #ffe7e8; border: 2px solid #e66465; line-height: 1.5;">Information incidents informatique majeur en cour :</p>
                <br>
                <marquee>
                        <object id="ObjAlertePageLogin" width="300" height="100" type="text/plain" data="test.txt" border="0" style="overflow: hidden;"></object>
                </marquee>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var newUrl = 'Alerte_PageLogin1.txt';
            var divEl = document.getElementById('DivAlertePageLogin');
            var objEl = document.getElementById('ObjAlertePageLogin');
            objEl.data = newUrl;
            // Refresh the content
            divEl.innerHTML = divEl.innerHTML;
            
            //var content = document.getElementById('ObjAlertePageLogin').value
            //var content = document.getElementById('ObjAlertePageLogin').innerText;
            //alert(content);
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //function or code for get content file Alerte_PageLogin1.txt
            var  ObjText = ""; // variable content file Alerte_PageLogin1.txt
            var  Disable = "N/A";
            if (Disable == ObjText) {
                document.getElementById("DivAlertePageLogin").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("DivAlertePageLogin").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("DivAlertePageLogin").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Alerte_PageLogin1.txt**

```
New alerte on server one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my prob

```
<Html>
    <Head>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache" content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-Control" content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive: no-cache">
        <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive: no-cache">
    </Head>
    <body>
        <div id="webLink">
            <div id="DivAlertePageLogin">
                <p style="background: #ffe7e8; border: 2px solid #e66465; line-height: 1.5;">Information incidents informatique majeur en cour :</p>
                <br>
                <marquee>
                    <object id="ObjAlertePageLogin" width="300" height="100" type="text/plain" data="test.txt" border="0" style="overflow: hidden;"> </object>
                </marquee>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        var newUrl = 'Alerte_PageLogin1.txt';
        var divEl = document.getElementById('DivAlertePageLogin');
        var objEl = document.getElementById('ObjAlertePageLogin');
        objEl.data = newUrl;
        // Refresh the content
        divEl.innerHTML = divEl.innerHTML;
        
        //La fonction ci-dessous ne fonctionne correctement si la page web est appeler a partir d'un serveur web externe et NON localement directement dans un navigateur
        getText("Alerte_PageLogin1.txt");
        async function getText(file) {
            let myObject = await fetch(file);
            let myText = await myObject.text();
            //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myText;
        
            var  ObjText = myText;
            var  Disable = "";
            if (Disable == ObjText) {
                document.getElementById("DivAlertePageLogin").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("DivAlertePageLogin").style.visibility = "hidden";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("DivAlertePageLogin").style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</Html>
```